# Format data for chart

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble formatting/transforming some simple data into a format that I can use to graph, and I'm hoping someone might help me solve. Currently, I have something like this

```
somedata= 
    {test1: {good: 3, bad: 2, redo: 2}}
    {test2: {good: 4, bad: 3}}
    {test3: {good: 3, redo: 4}}
```

into something like

```
series: 
[{name: "good", data: [3,4,3]}, 
{name: "bad", data: [2,3,0]}, 
{name: "redo", data: [2,0,4]}]
```

I can grab the categories by using `Object.keys(somedata)` easy enough i.e. `['test1', 'test2', 'test3']` but having problem formatting the rest of the data. I tried something like

```
 let combine = {};
                Object.values(somedata).map((row) => {
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
                        combine.hasOwnProperty(key)
                            ? combine[key].push(value)
                            : (combine[key] = [value]);
                    }
                    console.log("combined", combine);
                });
```

but quickly realized that it won't add `0` when key doesn't exist, which is required for the chart to compare between the different series, such as bar charts. So, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can first collect all unique values and then using `array#reduce` and other array methods generate all the values corresponding to each key in an object accumaltor.

```js
const somedata = [{test1: {good: 3, bad: 2, redo: 2}}, {test2: {good: 4, bad: 3}}, {test3: {good: 3, redo: 4}}],
      uniqueValues = [...new Set(
        somedata.reduce((r,o) => {
          Object.values(o).forEach(ob => {
           r.push(...Object.keys(ob));
          });
          return r;
        }, [])
      )];
      result = Object.values(somedata.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.values(o).forEach(ob => {
          uniqueValues.forEach(k => {
            r[k] = r[k] || { name: k, data: []};
            ob[k] ? r[k].data.push(ob[k]): r[k].data.push(0);
          });
        });
        return r;
      },{}));
      
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This will collect the data, but still will not adding the `0` values to the arrays that are required for the chart data. As you can see from the example output, without adding the `0`, the context will be lost, and the chart with graph incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the answer to add 0 for missing keys. We will first get all unique keys and for each object, we will check if that key exists in our object, and based on that we will add 0 and value.

Answer (score 1):

something like this: for each test, group categories (can optionally restrict to a subset) - assume Zero for missing category

```
const someData = {test1: {good: 3, bad: 2, redo: 2}, test2: {good: 4, bad: 3}, test3: {good: 3, redo: 4}};

function prepMyGraphData(data, fields) {

    let out = {
    }

    for (const [k, el] of Object.entries(data)) {
        const _fields = new Set((fields || Object.keys(el)).concat(Object.keys(out)));
        for (const f of _fields) {
            const v = el.hasOwnProperty(f) ? el[f] || 0 : 0 ; // own field or 0
            if (out.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                out[f].data.push(v) // existing category
            }else{
                out[f] = {name: f, data: [v]} // new category entry
            }
        }
    }
    return Object.values(out)
}

let fields = ['good', 'bad', 'redo']; // OR, undefined, for ALL own properties
const data = prepMyGraphData(someData, fields);
```

Comment: This would require a list of all possible fields as input, and not inferred from the available fields in the data, correctly? I've run some tests and will report back. Thank you.

Comment: i've made the fields optional, so now, if you care to restrict to just the given fields, it groups on those, otherwise, groups on all categories found.